# Can I trigger lambda only when message count reaches target value in SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm writing AWS Lambda to read message from SQS and then save some messages to S3 after filtering. Since 80% messages will be filtered out, I decided write S3 once for 100000 SQS messages.

Is it possible to trigger the Lambda only when the messages in SQS reach 10000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible with help of [AWS CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/).

You could configure an AWS CloudWatch Alarm which triggers an "AlarmAction" as soon as your SQS queue got 100000 visible messages. In case of an "Alarm" you are notifying a SNS Topic which then triggers your AWS Lambda.

If you are using [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) it might look as the following:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  Queue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

  QueueVisibleMessagesTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic

  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

  Lambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: handler.index
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 10

  LambdaSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !GetAtt Lambda.Arn
      Protocol: lambda
      TopicArn: !Ref QueueVisibleMessagesTopic

  LambdaSubscriptionPermissions:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt Lambda.Arn
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Ref QueueVisibleMessagesTopic

  QueueVisibleMessagesAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      Namespace: AWS/SQS
      MetricName: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
      Dimensions:
        - Name: QueueName
          Value: !GetAtt Queue.QueueName
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 300
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Threshold: 100000
      AlarmActions:
        - !Ref QueueVisibleMessagesTopic
```