# SQS Min Batch size when triggering Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, eventtrigger

I have an SQS queue that gets messages into it not very frequently. And I want to run a lambda when there are enough items in the queue to process (let's say 10).

Is there any way to trigger a lambda from SQS when there are minimum of x items in the queue?

The `BatchSize` doesn't work, as it's the maximum number of items that will appear in a batch instead of minimum.

By the way I'm looking for simple ways to do this instead of keeping track of number of items in queue in a db/storage solution and triggering lambda conditional to that.

Comment: You can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54089891/12326605